# CodeIgniter check if query succeeded

Tags: php, codeigniter

I searched online and most of them suggest to use `num_rows` or similar functions to check if the query has been successful in CodeIgniter, however I am using an `update` function

```
$data = array(
  'title' => $title,
  'name' => $name,
  'date' => $date
);

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data); 

// Produces:
// UPDATE mytable 
// SET title = '{$title}', name = '{$name}', date = '{$date}'
// WHERE id = $id
```

How would I check if this query was successful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`$this->db->affected_rows()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)

Comment: When we don't change anything and query doesn't fail, $this->db->affected_rows() will returns FALSE (but hasn't happened any errors!).

Comment: This is because it returns zero which can be interpreted as false in some cases. You should compare the result with zero in order to get a more reliable boolean result.

Answer (score 2):

`affected_rows()` won’t give you proper results with this method, due to the very nature of how it works. Instead, `update_batch()` returns the number of rows affected.

*ELSE TRY USING:*

```
$result = $this->db->update('mytable', $data);
if ($result) {
    return 1;
}
```